# Location variables in the pom.xml file do not work on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu, pom.xml

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and Eclipse Oxygem March 2018.

I have a project on a ntfs partition. My pom.xml is in this directory: /media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons/pom.xml

I am using the variable ${basedir} (I also tested the ${project.basedir} variable) to find this location.

These variables should contain the following directory: /media/gustavo/Novo volume/GIT/sistemas/Comuns/commons/

(It works in Windows 10)

But, on Ubuntu 18.04, it is showing the following location: /home/gustavo/.m2/repository/

Does anyone know how to make this variable point to the right place in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding in the systemPath resource the following address $ {project.basedir} ../../

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}../../commons/target/commons-0.0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```